# jQuery - Find active class from one list item and give this class to another list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two indicator lists of bootstrap carousel

First

```
<ol class="rightci carousel-indicators">
  <li class="active" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" ></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2" ></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3" ></li>
</ol>
```

Second

```
<div class="left leftci carousel-indicators">
<a href=""><span class="leftindicators" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0">slide1</span></a>
<a href=""><span class="leftindicators" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1">slide2</span></a>
<a href=""><span class="leftindicators" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2">slide3</span></a>
<a href=""><span class="leftindicators" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3">slide4</span></a>
</div>
```

what I want to do is check, if children of First list has `active` class and and give active class to Second list children  on the same index number where first list have active class.

As fist list is carousel indicator list.... it changes as `carousel item` changes

For Example:
If third item from first list has class `active` then give `active` to the third item of the second list

jQuery I tried(I am new to jQuery)

```
var index = $('#rcl li.active').parent().index();
    $('#lcl span.activelink').removeClass('activelink');
    $('#lcl span').eq(index).addClass('activelink');
```

Where i am rit now Just example...i want to move active class on both indicators https://jsfiddle.net/ppwn8oau/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
var index = $('#rcl li.active').attr('slide-to');
$('#lcl span.activelink').removeClass('activelink');
$('#lcl span[slide-to=' + index + ']').addClass('activelink');
```

**EDIT**

```js
$('#rcl li').click(function(event) {

  // set active to the clicked element
  $('#rcl li.active').removeClass('active');
  $(event.target).addClass('active');

  // get active element
  var index = $('#rcl li.active').attr('data-slide-to');

  // apply active to the second list
  $('#lcl span.activelink').removeClass('activelink');
  $('#lcl span[data-slide-to=' + index + ']').addClass('activelink');

});
```

```css
#rcl li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#rcl li.active {
  color: red;
}
#lcl span.activelink {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ol id="rcl" class="rightci carousel-indicators">
  <li class="active" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0">one</li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1">two</li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2">three</li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3">four</li>
</ol>

<div id="lcl" class="left leftci carousel-indicators">
  <a href=""><span class="leftindicators activelink" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0">slide1</span></a>
  <a href=""><span class="leftindicators" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1">slide2</span></a>
  <a href=""><span class="leftindicators" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2">slide3</span></a>
  <a href=""><span class="leftindicators" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3">slide4</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it works fine on click :)....  there is one more proble `rightci ` is indicator of carousel slider it's `.active` class  changes automatically on slider change..... What i want is `leftci` also change class with it

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var index = $('.rightci li.active').data('slide-to');    
$('.rightci li').removeClass('active');    
$('.leftci a')eq(index).find('span').addClass('active');
```